# Group PHP Array and get Maximum values and Sum of the Maximum Values

Tags: php

I have post data form and need array group by value, select max value and sum max value
I have an idea foreach but I can’t get the right value. The array is as follow and HTML code available at the bottom

```
Array
(
    [company] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC
            [1] => BBC
            [2] => BBC
            [3] => ABC
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 15
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Output:-

```
1-ABC-10
4-ABC-15 …….Max price 15
2-BBC-5
3-BBC-20 ……. Max price 20
Total Price 35
```

Html Form:-

```
<form action="?" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
      Company: <input name="company[]" type="text" id="company[]" value="ABC"><br>
      Price: <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price[]" value="10">
      <br>
      Company: <input name="company[]" type="text" id="company[]" value="BBC"><br>
      Price: <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price[]" value="5">
      <br>
      Company: <input name="company[]" type="text" id="company[]" value="BBC"><br>
      Price: <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price[]" value="20">
      <br>
      Company: <input name="company[]" type="text" id="company[]" value="ABC"><br>
      Price: <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price[]" value="15">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is that the output you want? Or the output you get? Can you show us you code as well please

Comment: I tried but i cant to get

Comment: Having duplicated element ids in an HTML document invalid.  Your desired output format seems a little clumsy to me.  Can you express exactly what output variables should be declared and their exact data from your sample input? @Dere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comapy = array("ABC","BBC","BBC","ABC");
$price  = array(10,5,20,15);

//Group Your data Here ABC[10,15] ..

$group = array();
foreach($comapy as $key=>$val){
     $group[$val][] = $price[$key];
}

// this loop for check the max number and count total price
$data   = array();
$total  = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$val){
    $data[][$key] = $key."-".current($val);
    $data[][$key] = $key."-".max($val)." Max price : ".max($val);
    $total        +=max($val);
}

// this foreach to convert your data to string
$result = "";
foreach($data as $key){
    $result .= "\n".current($key);
}
// and show your data like string
print_r($result);
print_r("\nTotal Price ".$total);

/**
 result :
 
 ABC-10
 ABC-15 Max price : 15
 BBC-5
 BBC-20 Max price : 20
 Total Price 35

 //*************If you have more than 4 data in your array remplace foreach 
 $groups with this code

 foreach($group as $key=>$val){
    for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
       if($val[$i]!==max($val))
       $data[][$key] = $key."-".$val[$i];
    }
    $data[][$key] = $key."-".max($val)." Max price : ".max($val);
    $total        +=max($val);
 }

 **/
```

Comment: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1Gx i tried very good result. but many company cant be list only current row i want list all and finally put max

Comment: php array grouping by variable I tested https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1LA